# Cats typeclass for isomorphic types

Tags: scala, scala-cats

What cats typeclass should I use to encode that two types are Isomorphic (i.e. can be converted back and forth without effects)

I want to encode the decomposition of a type into a tuple of two others:
`A <=> (B, C)`

Obviously, the typeclass should expose the two functions for each direction of the conversion, and ideally implicit methods for convenient conversion.
Something like this: (but failed to find it)

```
trait Iso[A,B] {
  def to(a: A):B
  def from(b: B): A
}
```

Comment: According to [this blog entry](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Isomorphism.html) *" Cats doesn’t seem to have a datatype to represent isomorphisms"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [`cats.evidence.Is`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/evidence/Is.scala)?

```
type A
type B

type X = Is[A, B] // A Is B

val a: A = ???
val b: B = ???
val x: A Is B = ???
val y: B Is A = ???

x.coerce(a): B
y.coerce(b): A
```

It's similar to [`scalaz.Leibniz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/8.0.x/base/shared/src/main/scala/scalaz/data/Leibniz.scala).

Comment: actually `Is` is quite different from Isomorphism. `Is` requires you to define `substitute`: `F[A] => F[B]`, which is more difficult than `A <=> B`.
I am still wondering if cats has isomorphism? (for example I can define `Duration <=> Double`, but do not know how to define `Is[Duration, Double]`)

Comment: @ISeeVoices Well, it defines an isomorphism. `x.coerce(_)` is direct mapping, `y.coerce(_)` is inverse mapping. Surely not every isomorphism can be defined so.